# Passing NSArray between ViewController. Is it by pointer or by copy?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, uiviewcontroller, nsarray

Given two UIViewControllers A and B. A sits on top of a UINavigationController. B has init function initWithArray. B was made and initWithArray in A. Then B was pushed into the NavigationController to sit on top of A.

In A, this is the array that was passed in

```
NSArray *arrayInA; //(assuming all init and everything was done)
```

Making B

```
B *b = [[B alloc]initWithArray: arrayInA];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: B animation: YES];
```

In B, initWithArray goes something like this

```
if (self){
    arrayInB = arrayFromA;
}
```

arrayInB is just private property in B

```
NSArray *arrayInB;
```

The question is, which of these are different objects? arrayInA / arrayFromA / arrayInB

Edit: I am working with ARC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code arrayInB points to the same memory address as arrayFromA which points to arrayInA. I would suggest changing your code so that arrayInB keeps a reference to the array it receives.

```
if (self){
   arrayInB = [arrayFromA retain];
}
```

or

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray * arrayInB;

if (self){
   self.arrayInB = arrayFromA;
}
```

If you want arrayInB to be its own array that points to the same objects as arrayFromA then you should do this.

```
if(self){
   self.arrayInB = [NSArray arrayWithArray:arrayFromA];
}
```

Comment: What I would like to happen is all three point to the same array. And I am working in ARC (sorry did not put that up). If I understand you correctly, what I am doing is giving me exactly what I want?

Comment: Thank you, and since you came first, I will mark yours as correct, even though others were correct too.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've only created a single array (that code is not shown, but referred to by your comment "assuming all init and everything was done") only one instance exists and all three references point to that instance.

Answer (score 1):

Given the information you provide, arrayInA should have the same address value as arrayInB, therefore they will point to the same object. This is because instance variables use 'assign' setter semantics.

You can always check to make sure by printing the pointer addresses:

```
- (id) initWithArray:(NSArray*)arrayFromA {
    ...
    if (self) {
      arrayInB = arrayFromA;
      NSLog(@"arrayInA:%x arrayInB:%x", arrayInA, arrayInB);
      ...
    }
    return self;
}
```